# Creating Fedora RPMs with a defined Vendor

Tags: rpm, fedora

I would like all of my organizations RPMs to have a vendor defined so we can easily see which of our RPMs are installed.  Does anyone know why Fedora says:

> Do **not** use these tags:
>      Packager
>      Vendor
>      Copyright

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

They give no reasoning at all.

If not using "Vendor" are there recommendations as to another method that is commonly used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with RPMs generally.

http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Specfile_guidelines Has good details, but....

- **Packager** Best used if your RPMs are never, ever going to be repackaged by anyone.
- **Vendor** Frequently auto-set by build systems (so it may be good in your case).
- **Copyright** Deprecated in favor of the `License` tag.

Comment: The [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Tags) state: `The Vendor tag should not be used. It is set automatically by the build system.`

Comment: Thanks Michael, but currently I don't see any vendor being set.  For example, if I do rpm -qi <mypackage> | grep -i vendor nothing is printed.  Where as for most other packages on my system the vendor is "Fedora Project".

Answer (score 0):

The **Packager** tag discouragement is poorly worded--I think the intent would be clearer something like this: "Don't hard-code your name in the **Packager** field in the RPM specfile. The `rpmbuild` tool will fill it in from the macro, if defined." Where macro can be defined like this:

```
rpmbuild --define "packager $USER@$HOSTNAME" | grep -i packager

-8: packager    yourname@yourhost.example.com
```